# Does MongoDB need caching?

Tags: mongodb, memcached

When I use only MongoDB and retrieve data from MongoDB 1000 times, the process has completed just for 10 seconds. After that, I combine Memcached and MongoDB, in this way, all data retrieved from Mongo has been stored in Memcached before, and I get data from Memcached but it takes 2 minutes to accomplish the task !

So anyone has a new way to improve performance, please tell me. My system is foreseen that there will be about 1000 request/second to services. Therefore, I feel worried about that.

Comment: what exactly is your question? you want to have performance better than 10 seconds that MongoDB gives you?  Then you will need to give more information about your data, indexing, resources, etc.

Comment: btw, MongoDB already uses its own in-memory caching of recently accessed data so it's no wonder memcached didn't help.  the question is whether mongod is actually your limiting factor - how parallelized were your application requests?  How did you send your queries?  if you did 1000 retrieves serially then it's no wonder you couldn't go faster - your application would be the limiting factor.  Try sending more of the requests in parallel and see how many can be handled then.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB uses disk for storing data while memchahed is an inmemory database. Ideally Memcached is faster than mongo. I have seen this for 500+ request /second.

When it comes to caching i don't anything much configurable.

In my setup , am using combination of Mongo , Memchaed and Redis DB, i use,

> Redis to store the Index of content , this index tell me where my data is stored weather in mongo or memchaed or on disk.
>
> MongoDB is used to store files smaller than 1 MB , files greater than 1 MB are stored in disk.

***RedisDB is also used to stores the hit count of a particular content , let say contecnt ABC is requested 3 times , so this count 3 is also stored in RedisDB along with Index. Based on hit count i will move the content from Mongo to Memcached.
Once data is moved from Mongo to Memcached , the index is also updated accordingly.

> so , Memcached is used for frequently accessed content .

I used memchaed with following options ,

---

memcached -d -m 8192 -P /home/setup/pid/.memcache.info -u root -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11211 -t 50 -n 1024

---

This architecture worked out for me quite well . Storing data index in redis could also help you save time searching data there.

Comment: MongoDB, Memcached and Redis? Isn't that kind of overkill, I would be really interested to know how much utilisation you really have, most likely any need for Redis and Memcached is based on the fact that you have not optimised MongoDB. I mean why do you query one in memory db to query another??

Comment: I need to that because i have variety of data to be stored in cache that is distributed over Mongo, MemcacheD and Disk. The reasons for storing data by three means because of the fact that I am storing files ranges from 10 KB to 1 GB. So storing 1 GB file in a mongo dosen't make much sense to me , but i have to store it .
With data distributed all over applications and disk , I need to search the availability of data on server on reception of every new request, which will definately cumbersome task when you have over half a million files over 4 TB storage. Indexing data on redis makes it fast

Comment: Hmm an in memory file server, odd but I am not there to see it as such I cannot judge it too much, however, it should be noted that your case is extremely unique and won't apply to 90% of other peoples cases, in their cases your solution would be way overkill

Comment: I feel every requirement/solution is unique in some or other way . What matters is to solve these unique problems is knowledge of technology and passion to solve the problems. 
My intent is to give idea about , how I made the use of redis , MongoDb and Memcached to resolve similar kind of problem that @Dennis Do mentioned in post .

Comment: I don't see anything about file server or anything in his post, in fact his post is extremely broad, there is no link between your scenario and his except that he might be overusing or wrongly using memcached.